# Chrome developer tool doesn't change the site

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-developer-tools

I have this very odd issue when using Google Chrome Developer tool where it "looks like" it just zooms out when I try to change the device.

When I minimize the browser window and manually make it smaller it works fine as shown in the picture below:

[image]

The css changes and everything is good.

However when I use the developer tool to change it to say a mobile device nothing really happens:

[image]

Why is this happening?

I am using version `86.0.420.111`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following to your code inside your `<head>` tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Without it the page would not be responsive on mobile.

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)